# How to set default mentions using ui-mention angularjs library?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Any ideas on how to set default mentions using ui-mention angularjs library (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mention)? For example, in the text area always have two default mentions (bob baker and Kenny Logins) as in the attached picture
[image]

Thanks for your helps, folks.

Answer (score 2):

By adding some users mentions you will see at the bottom the model related:

```
ng-model (post.message): "hi there @[bob barker:11123]"
```

so for your example, initializing it is like:

```
$rootScope.post = {
    message: "hi there @[bob barker:11123] @[kenny logins:123ab-123]"
};
```

But you will notice that it doesn't work.
After taking a look in the code it will work if you are able to add theses users in `$mention.mentions` and because `$mention` is the `controllerAs` in the uiMention directive, you are able to set it in the custom directive (mentionExample in the example) by `uiMention.mentions`.
So by adding:

```
uiMentions.mentions = uiMention.mentions.push(choices[0]); //bob barker
uiMentions.mentions = uiMention.mentions.push(choices[1]); //kenny logins
```

in the `function link` in the mentionExample, this would work.

But I think you should make it dynamically (in this link function) by searching in $scope.post.message all @mentions and then adding the relating user item in uiMentions.mentions.

Take a look on this plunker I created for you: http://embed.plnkr.co/o3mByKttPthpiqe4O5x6/

Comment: perfect, this is exactly what I need. Thanks mate

Comment: @HungVu no problem, could you mark it as solved then?